# 403 forbidden to localhost root MAMP Pro v2.2

Tags: apache, mamp, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a 403 forbidden error on my localhost root. I think it's an apache error. I'm on a MBP OSX 10.7, MAMP Pro 2.2.

apache log:

```
    client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/
```

I've tried, with cc all every time;

Looking for documents/tutorials on 2.2

Fresh upgrade and install, and reinstalls

Checking ownership/changing permissions to 777

[These](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/)

Changing the MAMP ports

changing the apache.conf directory, including trying various Options, from

```
    Options Includes
    AllowOverride None
```

to

```
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
```

Please help, I'm feeling at my wits end and I'm not familiar with apache Directory perms

Answer (score 19):

You can try the following method. 
In MAMP PRO Panel, go to "Host" > "Advanced" > check the "Indexes" and apply it.

Comment: This is now Hosts > Extended > Indexes

Comment: thank you this worked for me, saved me from digging around the httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 3):

On the Mac 3.0.5 version of MAMP Pro the tab you need to select is Extended.  Here's what the Mamp documentation says "Indexes
Activates or deactivates "directory browsing". If there is no index.html, index.php, etc in the document root, the content of the folder is displayed when this option is enabled. Without this option, nothing will be displayed or an error message will appear."

Answer (score -1):

**MAMP PRO 4**

1. Click Hosts -> Apache.
2. check the "indexes" checkbox.
3. Click the Save button.

See the attached image.

[image]

Comment: You're not really adding any useful information to this question. It was asked and answered about 7 years ago and your answer is almost a carbon copy of the top answer.